# Google Doc API (JavaScript) - batchUpdate - updateTextStyle foregroundColor returns 500?

Tags: javascript, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have an app that generates copies a document then runs batch update on the new file. When trying to use updateTextStyle I keep getting a 500 error without much detail. My entire request returns fine without foreground color, including inserting a table and multiple replace text requests.

This error also occurs when just doing it on a basic text document via the try it out feature.

For the easiest example, using the [Google Docs API Try It](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate?apix=true), I run the following on a blank google doc I created in my root directory with the text 'TEST COLOR CHANGE GOOGLE DOC' and nothing else.

Code I execute:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "updateTextStyle": {
        "fields": "foregroundColor",
        "range": {
          "startIndex": 1,
          "endIndex": 3,
        },
        "textStyle": {
          "foregroundColor": {
            "color": {
              "rgbColor": {
                "blue": 255,
                "green": 0,
                "red": 0
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Error I get back:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
```

I've tried various ways and nothing seems to be working. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to modify `foregroundColor` using the method of documents.batchUpdate in Google Docs API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

I think that your request body is mostly correct. But about `rgbColor`, please modify as follows. I think that your error message is due to this. In [the official document](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#RgbColor), it says as follows.

> - red: The red component of the color, from 0.0 to 1.0.
> - green: The green component of the color, from 0.0 to 1.0.
> - blue: The blue component of the color, from 0.0 to 1.0.

From this, please modify the property of `rgbColor` in your request body as follows.

#### From:

```
"rgbColor": {
  "blue": 255,
  "green": 0,
  "red": 0
}
```

#### To:

```
"rgbColor": {
  "blue": 1,
  "green": 0,
  "red": 0
}
```

#### Reference:

- [RgbColor](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#RgbColor)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: You are the BEST! I don't know how I missed this, thank you so much for your thoughtful and detailed answer!

Comment: @Almost_Ashleigh Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I think that this might be the reason of it. The specification for the color value is different between [Document service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/rgb-color.html and [Docs API](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#RgbColor). I was also confused for this. This experience was help to find the modification point.

Comment: none of the color pickers I have found give the colors in 0.0 to 1.0.  Just divide the 0 - 255 by 255 to get the 0.0 to 1.0 value needed for batchUpdate.  Thanks Tanaike!